# Error when trying to create my databases on each of the DB Context

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, identityserver4

I have an ASP.NET Core web app that I want to add ASP.NET Identity and Entity Framework support for my IdentityServer4 solution. I added migrations to my solution then ran the cmd

```
dotnet tool install--global dotnet-ef
```

to run `dotnet-ef` cmds, then ran the following cmds:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c PersistedGrantDbContext

dotnet ef migrations add InitialIdentityServerMigration -c ConfigurationDbContext
```

After that I attempted to create my databases by calling the `dotnet ef database update` on each of the DB contexts... when I run the cmd:

```
dotnet ef database update -c PersistedGrantDbContext
```

I get a message "build started", then the build succeeds but in the end, I get an error. Not sure why I am getting this error:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (53): The network path was not found.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
> at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.b__0(DateTime giveUp)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
> Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

In my `startup` file I have the following:

```
namespace id
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTestUsers(Config.Users)
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = builder => builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                        sqlOptions => sqlOptions.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());

        }
    }
}
```

in my `appsettings.json` I have

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=IdentityServer.db;"
  }
```

When I go to Sql Server Config. Manager I have the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am running `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in my project...

Is the reason why I am getting that error when I am trying to update my database is because I do not have it set up or is there a specific thing that is causing this? Also, is there a way to use SQL Server Express instead of SQL Server for what I am trying to do?

Comment: Check out [connectionstrings.com](https://connectionstrings.com) - your connection string is very weird and most likely the cause of this error. It should be something like `data source=YourMachine\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=YourDatabaseName;` and then you also need to either specify database user and password (`User ID`, `Pwd`) or use integrated security (Windows auth) using `Integrated Security=SSPI;`.

Comment: So with `connectionstring` I thought that would be the file that gets created in the project? So you're saying for connectionstring, I actually have to create a database?

Comment: Could I do the following: `"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;database=Test.IdentityServer4.EntityFramework;trusted_connection=yes;"` ? allowing for it to create a db named `Test.IdentityServer4.EntityFramework`?

Comment: I would try to use a **simpler** database name - no spaces, no dots - just a simple name - `IdentityServerDB` or something like that. And if you're using SQL Server Express, you're not dealing with files - you just define a **database** (by name) to be created and used on the SQL Server - let the file fiddling to the server.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and explanation I understand now! Very much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's right there in the error message, to me:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Much appreciated! :)